# "Problem on / at my end / side"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

What can we use in this case? Let's say there is a phrase:

"Is it a bug in the software or something ***on / at*** my ***end / side***?".

I.e. the person asks whether this is a bug in the software or the problem occurs due to some misconfiguration on the user's machine for example.

Answer (score 1):

**At my end** and **on my side** are equally appropriate phrases here.

**At my side** would signify something quite different, such as a very awkward person.

**On my end** is possible but not as idiomatic as **at my end**.

Comment: What do you mean with "such as a very awkward person"? At your side? So it would become "is it a bug in the software or a very awkward person at my side?"?

Comment: **At my side** would signify **sitting beside me**, whether a person, a distracting child, a demanding animal or you name it.

Comment: Okay, so that was just a very specific example?